# How to Update properties of a word in cloud using Microsoft Graph

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

How to Update properties of a word in cloud using Microsoft Graph
Can you please help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Word API available under the Microsoft Graph.

You can [submit an idea](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) to bring Word API into Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Could I use third party api? And if yes which is the best?

Comment: @user17681081 It depends what exactly you need to modify and which version of Word document (2003,2007,etc.) you need to modify.